# Navigating through a sequence of URLs

Tags: html, jquery

I’m trying write javascript for navigation buttons (Previous/Next) through a sequence of web pages. The list of page urls is present in the same html as the buttons.

So using the below example, if I’m on the ‘test_pg5.htm’ page, clicking Previous should go to ‘test_pg4.htm’ and clicking Next should go to ‘test_coursecomplete.htm’.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li data-mc-id="0"><a href="../../courses/test/comms_view_intro.htm">Main Course Page</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li data-mc-id="1"><a href="../../courses/test/test_pg1.htm">Topic 1</a></li>
            <li data-mc-id="2"><a href="../../courses/test/test_pg2.htm">Topic 2</a></li>
            <li data-mc-id="3"><a href="../../courses/test/test_pg3.htm">Quiz 1</a></li>
            <li data-mc-id="4"><a href="../../courses/test/test_pg4.htm">Topic 3</a></li>
            <li data-mc-id="5"><a href="../../courses/test/test_pg5.htm" class="selected" aria-current="true">Quiz 2</a></li>
            <li data-mc-id="6"><a href="../../courses/test/test_coursecomplete.htm">Course Completion Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<button class="prevLink">Previous</button>
<button class="nextLink">Next</button>
```

Tried to use the answer from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644362/how-can-i-identify-the-previous-next-link-in-a-sequence-of-unordered-and-or-nest) to create the script below but it is not functioning.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.menu a'));
    var index = links.indexOf(currentFocus);

    $('.nextLink').click(function() {
        window.location.href = links[index + 1];
    });

    $('.prevLink').click(function() {
        window.location.href = links[index - 1];
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the value of `currentFocus`? I'm guessing the value of `index` on the third line isn't properly getting the current page link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

First, you don't need to convert querySelectorAll to an array.

For my answer, I'm checking to see if an element is selected, if it is get the parent's mcId and convert it to a number, if not set index to 0.

Then in my click events, I simply do checks to see if the index is at the end for next clicks or at the beginning for previous clicks. The if statements allow you to create the loop as they will adjust the index accordingly.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.menu a');
const selected = document.querySelector(".menu a.selected");
let index = (selected) ? Number(selected.parentNode.dataset.mcId) : 0

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nextLink').click(function() {

       index = (index === links.length - 1) ? 0 : index+1;
       console.log(links[index].href)
       // window.location.href = links[index].href;
    });

    $('.prevLink').click(function() {
        index = (index === 0) ? links.length - 1 : index-1;
        console.log(links[index].href)
        //window.location.href = links[index].href;
    });
});
```

```css
.selected{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li data-mc-id="0"><a href="../../courses/test/comms_view_intro.htm">Main Course Page</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li data-mc-id="1"><a href="../../courses/test/test_pg1.htm">Topic 1</a></li>
            <li data-mc-id="2"><a href="../../courses/test/test_pg2.htm">Topic 2</a></li>
            <li data-mc-id="3"><a href="../../courses/test/test_pg3.htm">Quiz 1</a></li>
            <li data-mc-id="4"><a href="../../courses/test/test_pg4.htm">Topic 3</a></li>
            <li data-mc-id="5"><a href="../../courses/test/test_pg5.htm" class="selected" aria-current="true">Quiz 2</a></li>
            <li data-mc-id="6"><a href="../../courses/test/test_coursecomplete.htm">Course Completion Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<button class="prevLink">Previous</button>
<button class="nextLink">Next</button>
```

Comment: thank you! this has gotten me much closer than before. The function is clearly running on button click and tries to open the url but it's coming up as ../courses/test/undefined

Comment: Updating the window.location.href = links[index].href; line is just resulting in no action on click. Console is registering the following: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'href')

Comment: @lc2301 the HTML that you have provided could be different or you have modified my code.  I just tested it out and it does work. Are you using a selected class somewhere else?

Comment: yes, I think that's it - the html is auto-generated by a CMS and the selected class is applied to the page in the course toc where we're pulling the urls for the buttons but also in the overall site nav. the .menu class is specific to the course toc list but the .selected class is used in both lists.

Comment: @lc2301 I updated my answer but you might need to modify it according to your specific needs. Basically the selector `document.querySelector(".menu a.selected")` would have to be specific for your navigation.